# Open "Add WiFi Network" screen programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-wifi

I want to open the **"+ Add Network"** screen (available inside the WiFi Settings) programmatically. I'm able to open the WiFi Settings screen successfully but that's not what I want.

I Just want to open the add network screen and close the settings when the back is pressed on that screen.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));
```

It will open the Wifi screen with the list of all available WIFI networks . you can connect on the network you want to connect.

In your case ,

you can try using  `public int addNetwork (WifiConfiguration config)` method from `WifiManager`.

for reference - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#addNetwork(android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration)

> and if you open the WIFI screen also , there you can click on Add
>   Network and it will open the new activity to add network
>
> One work-around , you can open your custom dialog to Add network ,
>   there you can take details like SSD , Password of that Network , and
>   then you can call `addNetwork(Configurations)` method of `WifiManager`.

Comment: This won’t work, I don’t want to allow the user to connect to available ‘scanned’ networks, I just want to allow to add the ssid, password and encryption (that is available inside the +Add Network) option. My application is running in kiosk mode.

Comment: check the updated answer , and if you open the WIFI screen also , there you can click on Add Network and it will open the new activity to add network

Comment: One work-around , you can open your custom dialog to Add network , there you can take details like SSD , Password of that Network , and then you can call addNetwork(Configurations) method of WifiManager.

Comment: Yes exactly I did the same!